# Issue with the segment in Google Analytics Reporting API V4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am migrating Google Analytics API from `V3` to `V4`. I seem to have come across a strange problem.

When I query for number of users `ga:users` with the segment `gaid::-1` which stands for **All Visitors**, in `V3` I get some number of users **x** and when I query the same parameters in `V4`, I am not getting the same number **x**. In fact the new number lets call it **y** is much greater than **x**. Almost twice of **x**.

Other metrics are all fine. Only `ga:users` is coming out to be a wrong value. Also, if I use some other segment like `gaid::-2` then it comes out to be the same value as in `V3`. The problem is with `gaid::-1` only.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: @DaImTo Can you help me with this?

Comment: could you show some JSON examples with your request parameters? Using [Request Composer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/) or [query exploerer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)